# need a 3-channel data logger

Tags: photodiode, datalogger

The second link shown below leads to the schematic for  measuring the position of a laser beam by using Quadrant PSD(Pg.No 45). I am trying to build a similar circuit. The datasheet of the quadrant PSD I am using is available in the first link. I want to use labVIEW for analyzing the three output voltages {((A+D)-(B+C)),((A+B)-(C+D)),(A+B+C+D)}in the circuit. can anyone suggest me a cost effective 3-channel data logger with PC connectivity suitable for my work.

http://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s4349_kmpd1007e02.pdf

http://www.osioptoelectronics.com/Libraries/Product-Data-Sheets/Quadrant-Bi-Cell-Photodiode.sflb.ashx

Comment: Have you actually read the datasheet at all? There is an example readout circuit schematic that is obviously entirely analog.

Comment: Have you called the number in that document and talked to an app-engineer?

Comment: Instead of asking the same question twice, you should edit your old question and we'll reopen it if suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outputs are definitely analog.

Page 45 of the PDF shows the circuit clearly:

The output from the 4 photo diodes pass through an integrator stage and then onto a summing matrix (all op amps) to the X and Y outputs. These values will indicate the X,Y (Cartesian) location of the beam.